# how to do code event which will generate at run time in .net winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I am getting checkedListBox values from database. Based on my checkbox selection it will perform some operation.where i have to write the code for checked items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the [`CheckListBox.ItemCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx) event. You can do this in code in your constructor or override to `OnLoad` or you can use the WinForms designer properties window events tab.

**In code** (where `checkListBox` is the name of your `CheckListBox`):

```
public MyType()
{
    this.checkListBox.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(OnCheckListBoxItemCheck);
}

private void OnCheckListBoxItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs args)
{
   //TODO: Do your operation...
}
```

**In the designer**:

1. Select your `CheckListBox` in the designer
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to view the Properties
3. Select the Events tab (indicated by a little lightning bolt)
4. Find the `ItemCheck` event and double-click - the event handler will be auto-generated and hooked up for you, you just need to add your code to make it do something

Answer (score 1):

Select the CheckedListBox in the designer, go to the Events tab in the Properties window, and double-click on any event.

Comment: if i have 3 item in the check box.based on the item i will do some operation so how can i check it value.because it will bind the data at run time.and the run time data changed every time